# Algorithm to find lines perpendicular to a given line of the form Ax+By+C=0

Tags: algorithm, math, line

Is there a way to find the lines perpendicular to a given lines given all the lines are of the form Ax+By+C=0?

I came up with a solution which takes quadratic running time. Is there a better way?

this is my code:

```
public class Perpendicular {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=in.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Line> list_of_lines=new ArrayList<Line>();
    for(long i=0;i<n;i++){
        long a=in.nextLong();
        long b=in.nextLong();
        long c=in.nextLong();
       list_of_lines.add(new Line(a,b,c));
    }
    long p[]=new long[n];
    Arrays.fill(p,0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<n;j++){
            if(list_of_lines.get(i).slope()*list_of_lines.get(j).slope()== -1){
                p[i]++;//num of perpendicular lines to i
                p[j]++;//num of perpendicular lines to j
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class Line{
public long a,b,c;
public Line(long a,long b,long c){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    this.c=c;
}
public double slope(){
    return a/b;
}
```

}

Comment: A hint, think of this problem in vector representation. This is more like a math problem then algorithm problem. Constant time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any line which is guided by the equation -Bx + Ay + D = 0 would be the set of lines perpendicular to the given family of lines(Ax + By + C = 0).

You just need to check and make sure that the product of their slopes are equal to -1.

So, a family of lines of the nature -Bx + Ay + D = 0 would satisfy this criteria.

To check all family of lines now is quite easy and is much easier than your expected quadratic solution.

EDIT :-

1. You don't need to run your loop in this way. Just ensure that when you've checked for perpendicularity between 2 lines, you don't perform the commutative check again. Ex; You checked perpendicularity between 1 and 2, then you don't need to duplicate your effort checking perpendicularity between 2 and 1. This should be avoided in your code by improving the second-loop initialisation by `j = i+1;`.
2. Using the suggested edit, you will also not need to check same lines for perpendicularity as that is impossible to be true. So, line k shouldn't be tested with itself for perpendicularity check. This has been easily resolved using the hint 1 itself.

Comment: @AmanArora - It seems you're comparing lines fed in the ArrayList for perpendicularityamong themselves. This is Ok. 1 minor improvement which you could perform I've added in the answer as an edit.

Comment: what is the improvement?

Comment: @AmanArora - The total iterations have decreased. Check out by displaying the count of total iterations. Feel the logic above, and you'll find the improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the equation to the form y = m*x + c, m is the slope and c is the y-intercept. Now, all lines perpendicular to this set of lines will have slope -1/m (perpendicular lines have slope product -1), which should give you the equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line `Ax + By + C = 0`, then perpendicular line `A1x + B1y + C1 = 0` should conform the dot product `v * v1 = 0` (* is [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) here). So `(A, B) * (A1 * B1) = A1 * A + B1 * B = 0`. Where one of the solutions is `A = -B1`, `B = A1`.

So your line has the form `Bx - Ay + C1 = 0`, where `C1` is any point. Which means that it is `O(1)`.

Comment: @AmanArora why do you need 2 pages of code. All that you need can be done in one line and I already showed you the line.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines would be perpendicular iff their slopes multiply to -1. (Assuming none of them are horizontal/vertical)

You can group the lines according to their slope in O(n log n).
For each pair of groups with perpendicular slopes each pair of lines in them would be an answer which you can iterate over. O(n lg n + num_of_answers)

Thus the algorithm would be O(n lg n + num_of_answers).

Note that there could be O(n^2) such pairs; but if you just need to find the number of such pairs, it could be found in O(n lg n).